# How does session based authentication work since we can't share cookie between different domains?

Tags: node.js, authentication, session, cookies, passport.js

I used google authentication in my MERN stack app using passport js. I have deployed frontend to vercel and backend to render. in my localhost, I can log in successfully and it returns cookies to my frontend from the backend. but in the deployed version when I try to log in it does log in but it doesn't return any cookies to the frontend. I did some research and found that cookies can't be shared between different domains. my question is should I host my backend in a subdomain and frontend in the main domain?

frontend: https://passport-frontend-seven.vercel.app/
backend : https://popupchat-backend.onrender.com/

// how i used express-session:

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "secretcode",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: true,
      domain: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // One Week
    },
  })
);

app.set("trust proxy", 1);
```

Comment: if you check the network tab after login, on set-cookie it says " this attempt to set a cookie via Set-Cookie header was blocked because its domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current url". I think this is happening because they are hosted on different domains.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct in your understanding that cookies can't be shared between different domains. If you have your frontend and backend deployed on different domains, then you will have difficulty accessing the cookies set by the backend in the frontend.

Hosting your backend on a subdomain of your main domain is one solution to this problem. For example, if your main domain is example.com, you can host your backend at api.example.com. This way, both the frontend and the backend will be under the same main domain and you will be able to share cookies between them.

However, there are other solutions as well, such as using a token-based authentication system, where the backend returns a token after a successful login, and the frontend can store this token in local storage or a cookie. The frontend can then send this token in the header of subsequent API requests to authenticate the user on the backend. This approach can be more secure than using cookies, since cookies are often stored in plain text and can be easily compromised.